# Copy Table on BigQuery without adding new fields on the destination table

Tags: google-bigquery

So I have a table (let's say `tableA`) in BigQuery and I want a duplicate table (`tableB`) of that but excluding some fields from the original. I tried to just put the schema on tableB with only the necessary fields (I excluded the fields I didn't want to copy) and then output an error `Provided Schema does not match Table ... cannot add fields ...`
Then I added metadata like in the [example](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/Table.html#copy) on the BigQuery's nodejs documentation reference:

`const metadata = {
  createDisposition: 'CREATE_NEVER',
  writeDisposition: 'WRITE_APPEND'
};
tableA.copy(tableB, metadata, (err, apiResponse) => {});`

but it ended to copy all the fields and created the fields I don't even want to copy.
So, I wonder if someone knows an option to not allow BigQuery to copy and create fields or should I load all the data in `tableA` and then re-insert them in `tableB`

Comment: So you want to copy only some columns in another table? Do you need to do that in Node Js or are you open to other solutions?

Comment: Yes, some columns but some here is like 1000+ columns, not 50 or less. I need to do that in NodeJS because it's what the client want, and also, they want to execute that copy frequently, not just once

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results), you can write a query as a table in `BigQuery`
In your case you could use the `BigQuery CLI` to create a query selecting everything but the fields that you don't want to copy. For example:

```
bq query \
--destination_table <destination_dataset.destination_table> \
--use_legacy_sql=false \
'SELECT
  <fields_that_you_want>
FROM
  <your_dataset.your_table>`
```

You can also use he flags `--replace` if you want your table destination to be overridden or `--append` if you want your query results to be appended in your table.

In this reference you can also find examples of how to that in some programming languages and in the `BigQuery API`

I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Send a query from nodejs, pick an easier one from below

```
CREATE TABLE table_b AS
SELECT * EXCEPT(col1_you_dont_want, col2_you_dont_want)
FROM table_a
```

Or

```
CREATE TABLE table_b AS
SELECT col1_you_do_want, col2_you_do_want
FROM table_a
```